# getting issue in @monaco-editor/react

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

./node_modules/@monaco-editor/react/dist/index.mjs 124:62
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (124:62)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |   k(() => {
  |     let i = Se.init();

> ```
> return i.then(f => (c.current = f) && s(!1)).catch(f => f?.type !== "cancelation" && console.error("Monaco initialization: error:", f)), () => u.current ? I() : i.cancel();
> ```

|   }), l(() => {
|     if (u.current && c.current) {

I tried various workaround, but nothing is working

Comment: Monaco Editor is buggy because the minifier Microsoft uses only understands Javascript and tries to minify regular expressions causing them to have errors.